# MySQL syntax error on PreparedStatement fails when multi-line, executes on single line

Tags: java, mysql, syntax-error

I keep getting this error and I can't for the life of me understand what's causing it:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= '111-11-1111'' at line 1`

It's being thrown by these statements:

```
ps = conn.prepareStatement(
         "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE NOT EXISTS"
         + "(SELECT * FROM courses"
         + "NATURAL JOIN register"
         + "WHERE ssn = ?)")
ps.setString(1,ssn);

rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

I've typed this exact command, character for character (except I replaced the ? with '111-11-1111'), into the MySQl Command Line Client, and it executed without a hitch. Yet, when I try to execute it with Java, it fails with the above syntax error. I have a sinking suspicion that the answer is extremely obvious and staring me in the face but I'm just too tired to see it. Any thoughts?

**Edit**
So I solved the immediate problem, but it just bring up more questions. If I structure the query as a single line string rather than a multi-line:

```
ps = conn.prepareStatement(
                "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM courses NATURAL JOIN register WHERE ssn = ?)");
```

It executes just fine. (Sorry about the horizontal scroll-bar, but in this case I don't have a choice.) So, I re-phrase my question: why in the pony-loving-frack does this make a difference? I'm using Java 7, Netbeans 7.2, and MySQL 5.5 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating a string using concatenation - try printing that string and you'll see the problem...
You don't have any spaces at the start or end of each substring, so the concatenated string will be:

```
"SELECT * FROM courses WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM coursesNATURAL JOIN registerWHERE ssn = ?)"
```

So `coursesNATURAL` and `registerWHERE` will be bad syntax.

Comment: AHA! I knew it was there, staring me in the face. Have an upvote, accept, and +1000 internetz from me.

Answer (score 2):

Both are single line (There is no \n / new-line in you first query either)

The problem is lack of space between breaking of each lines, i.e. after `FROM courses` you need a space.

So your first query is actually wrong. since it translates to :

```
 FROM **coursesNATURAL**
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you create a string in JAVA which spans over multiple lines, you make sure that you have space left after the first line or before the second line

```
+ "(SELECT * FROM courses"
     + "NATURAL JOIN register"
```

This would just resolve to

```
SELECT * FROM coursesNATURAL JOIN register"
```